# Sitefinity Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002"

Tags: installation, sitefinity

I trying to run a local instance of Sitefinity 8.0.5700.0.

**My steps to run site locally:**

1. Restored a backup of an existing database to (localdb)\v11.0 (database schema)
2. Setup IIS site named Default (binding localhost) in IIS under LocalSystem Indentity
3. DataConfig.config connection string changed to Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True;Database=Sitefinity
4. Run site http://localhost, runs and asks for license details. I apply trial license.
5. The site then errors with the below.

**YSOD:**

Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".

Exception Details: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid root node configured for pages. No root node with the name of "f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002".

**Things I have tried:**

I have contacted Sitefinity support and tried the steps outlined in the below link. Therefore ensured:

- Project names match in config and db (sf_page_node, sf_sites tables).
- Root node IDs match in config and db.
- Checked connection string

http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/knowledge-base/when-sitefinity-project-is-deployed-to-production-server-an-invalid-root-node-configured-for-pages-no-root-node-with-the-name-of-frontendsitemap-error-is-thrown

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is running the Sitefinity site under Full IIS under the ApplicationPoolIdentity with LocalDB. As the site doesn't have access to the LocalDB instance. The following article explains how to work around the issue, or simply just use IIS Express instead:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx

**How I got there:**

1. Running IIS Express (F5) through Visual Studio loads http://localhost:1234
2. I entered the license details. License gets rejected, I assume because of the port number 1234. Maybe a Sitefinity issue here, not allowing license registration with a port.
3. I then setup a site under Full IIS, for http://localhost. Hit the license screen and then entered fine.
4. Loading up the Full ISS (http://localhost) goes to the error.
5. However after then running IIS Express (with ports) the site loads.

Hopefully this helps some other poor soul!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Everytime I have received this a simple restore if the db has fixed it.